# laravel 5.5 group by on a single column doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.5

laravel 5.5 group by on a single column doesn't work even if i set the settings "strict" to false.. i have tried the raw query in the mysql workbench and it's working fine but i am having this error on laravel:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'hammer.vehicle.consignor_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `vehicle`.*, `vehicle_brand`.`vehicle_brand_name`, `vehicle_model`.`vehicle_model_name`, `vehicle_variant`.`vehicle_variant_name`, `vehicle_model`.`year`, `vehicle`.`vehicle_id` from `vehicle` left join `vehicle_brand` on `vehicle_brand`.`vehicle_brand_id` = `vehicle`.`vehicle_brand_id` left join `vehicle_model` on `vehicle_model`.`vehicle_brand_id` = `vehicle_brand`.`vehicle_brand_id` left join `vehicle_variant` on `vehicle_variant`.`vehicle_model_id` = `vehicle_model`.`vehicle_model_id` group by `vehicle`.`vehicle_id` limit 10 offset 0)
```

here is the laravel code that's causing the error

```
\DB::table('vehicle')
                    ->select('vehicle.*', 'vehicle_brand.vehicle_brand_name', 'vehicle_model.vehicle_model_name', 'vehicle_variant.vehicle_variant_name', 'vehicle_model.year', 'vehicle.vehicle_id')
                    ->leftJoin('vehicle_brand', 'vehicle_brand.vehicle_brand_id', '=', 'vehicle.vehicle_brand_id')
                    ->leftJoin('vehicle_model', 'vehicle_model.vehicle_brand_id', '=', 'vehicle_brand.vehicle_brand_id')
                    ->leftJoin('vehicle_variant', 'vehicle_variant.vehicle_model_id', '=', 'vehicle_model.vehicle_model_id')
                    ->where($where)
                    ->groupBy('vehicle.vehicle_id')
                    ->paginate(10);
```

The mysql settings in the config "strict" is already set to false

Comment: What is the $where variable. Can you add more details?

Comment: @LakiGeri $where variable can be empty or has where statements. for now it is set to an empty array

Comment: `vehicle.vehicle_id` i think there is a problem here no ? what is the id of the vehicle table ?

Comment: that is the primary key of the vehicle table.. that's our naming convention

Comment: Ok so in the select you have 'vehicle.*' and vehicle.vehicle_id may be  it's not the problem source but just for cleaning :p

Comment: tried removing vehicle.vehicle_id from the select. still it persist

Comment: maybe the problem with the DB, have you tried to run the SQL select what is in the error msg?

Comment: @LakiGeri i've run the raw query in the workbench. it worked. i've already said that on the question

Comment: you're right, im sorry. Maybe it misses the `->get();` from the end of the db query.

Comment: @LakiGeri i don't think ->get() is needed, i already have the ->paginate()

Comment: `for now it is set to an empty array` - can you try removing the `->where($where)` all together, as a test? Excluding the where, your query is really just a plain select, so there doesn't seem much that could go wrong.  Maybe having `->where([])` is causing problems?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's the Strict mode that causes the problem, check the `config/database.php` and check inside the `mysql`, and change

```
'strict' => true,
```

to

```
'strict' => false,
```

Because as mentioned in this [thread](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14997)

> If this is set to true then it'll add the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY when
>   querying.

Or you can try to disable the `only_full_group_by` setting by executing the following:

```
mysql> set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
mysql> set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/4881811).

Comment: i've already said in my question that i've set that to false. that's why it's weird because on laravel 5.4 doing that solves this problem. upgrading to laravel 5.5 it doesn't work.

Comment: Try to add `vehicle.consignor_id` to the groupBy just like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115425/4881811)